# Prolog definition which detects a path

Tags: prolog, graph-theory, transitive-closure

Context, first. I have the following **bi-directional** graph.

[image: Graph]

Represented in Prolog like this:

```
relation(a,c).
relation(b,d).
relation(c,d).
relation(d,e).
relation(e,f).

connection(X,Y) :- relation(X,Y).
connection(X,Y) :- relation(Y,X).
```

So I have the relation between the nodes, and then the connections between the nodes related, as I said before, in both directions.

What I am looking to do is a prolog definition `path(X,Y)` capable **to tell if there's a path in the graph between two nodes** (giving true if, at least, one path exists between both nodes, and false if there's no existing paths between both nodes).

So, the goal output in this model should look like this:

```
?- path(a,d).
true.

?- path(b,a).
true. 

?- path(f,b).
true

?  path(a,g).  % The node g doesn't exist
false.
```

I know this involves using a visited list, and I had seen examples of this, [but giving all the posible paths between two nodes](http://www.csupomona.edu/~jrfisher/www/prolog_tutorial/2_15.html). However, this isn't what I'm looking for. What I'm looking **is a definition which detects if there is a path between two nodes, not to give all the posible paths between two nodes**.

**Edit**: So, thanks to @mbratch, I can now adapt the suggested problem to a solution:

```
relation(a,c).
relation(b,d).
relation(c,d).
relation(d,e).
relation(e,f).

connection(X,Y) :- relation(X,Y).
connection(X,Y) :- relation(Y,X).

path_exists(X,Y) :- path(X,Y,_), !.

path(A,B,Path) :-
       travel(A,B,[A],Q), 
       reverse(Q,Path).

travel(A,B,P,[B|P]) :- 
       connection(A,B).
travel(A,B,Visited,Path) :-
       connection(A,C),           
       C \== B,
       \+member(C,Visited),
       travel(C,B,[C|Visited],Path).
```

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following what you want. Can't you take the solution given in the link you cited and change it to what you want? The link solves the problem of providing at paths between the nodes, and it sounds like you just want to know if a path exists between the nodes.

Comment: @mbratch What i'm looking is to know **if a path exists between the nodes**, nothing else.

Comment: If you run the example code shown in the link, if it returns at least one path, then you know a path exists. You can then do a little work to make it more efficient if needed. For example, have it stop when it finds the first path. It would fail if it found none. I think it's basically all the logic you need.

Comment: @mbratch Yes, but there's a difference, in the example shown in the link you are giving `path(X,Y,P)`, with `X` and `Y` as nodes of the graph, and `P`, as a path list. When you run the example shown `path(1,5,P)`, in this case, `P` will give you all the posible paths between the nodes. In this case I am asking for, I am giving just the nodes (`1` and `5` in the example of the link), so, supposing `1` and `5` are nodes of my graph, the goal output of my program should be giving me **just true or false**, not all the possible paths.

Comment: `path` in that example does everything you need. You can ignore `P`. You would have `path_exists(X, Y) :- path(X, Y, _), !.` and that's it. It stops if it finds one path and gives true. If it doesn't find a path, it gives false.

Comment: That's what I was asking for, I tested it and it worked. That leaves me just to adapt the problem to the program proposed. Thanks! =D

Answer (score 2):

What you want to get is commonly called "**[transitive closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_closure)** of a binary relation".

We can obtain the [transitive-closure](/questions/tagged/transitive-closure) of `connection/2` by using [meta-predicate](/questions/tagged/meta-predicate)  [`closure/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26946133/definition-of-reflexive-transitive-closure) like this:

```
% Q: Which `To` can be reached via `connection` starting at `From`?
?- closure(connection,From,To).
```

First, let's run the queries the OP gave:

```
?- closure(connection,a,d).
  true                                % OK: succeeds non-deterministically
; false.                      

?- closure(connection,b,a).
  true                                % OK: succeeds non-deterministically
; false.

?- closure(connection,f,b).
  true                                % OK: succeeds non-deterministically
; false.

?- closure(connection,a,g).
false.                                % OK: finitely fails
```

Let's ask the most general query!

```
?- closure(connection,X,Y).
  X = a, Y = c
; X = a, Y = d
; X = a, Y = e
; X = a, Y = f
; X = a, Y = b
; X = b, Y = d
; X = b, Y = e
; X = b, Y = f
; X = b, Y = c
; X = b, Y = a
; X = c, Y = d
; X = c, Y = e
; X = c, Y = f
; X = c, Y = b
; X = d, Y = e
; X = d, Y = f
; X = e, Y = f
; X = c, Y = a
; X = d, Y = b
; X = d, Y = c
; X = d, Y = a
; X = e, Y = d
; X = e, Y = b
; X = e, Y = c
; X = e, Y = a
; X = f, Y = e
; X = f, Y = d
; X = f, Y = b
; X = f, Y = c
; X = f, Y = a
false.
```