# Prolog, Determine if graph is acyclic

Tags: prolog, graph-theory, directed-acyclic-graphs, transitive-closure, meta-predicate

I need to define a predicate acyclic/1 that takes a graph in as input and determine if that graph is acyclic. So from my understanding

```
graph1(a,b).
graph1(b,c). 
graph1(c,a).
```

Will return no and

```
graph2(a,b).
graph2(b,c).
```

will return yes

I made a predicate to determine if 2 nodes in a graph are connected and if so they will return yes.

```
isConnected(X,Y) :- a(X,Z), isConnected(Z,Y).
```

is there a way that I can use this to determine if a graph is acyclic?

I do not want to use any predefined predicates.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read http://stackoverflow.com/tour to understand how this site works ; if an answer is OK to you, accept it by clicking on the checkmark!

Comment: Please do read the tour! Otherwise Stack Overflow will not be very helpful to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`closure0/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26946133/772868):

```
:- meta_predicate(acyclic(2)).
:- meta_predicate(cyclic(2)).

acyclic(R_2) :-
   \+cyclic(R_2).

cyclic(R_2) :-
  closure0(R_2, X0,X),
  call(R_2, X,X0).

?- acyclic(graph2).
   true.
?- acyclic(graph1).
   false.
```

`cyclic/1` succeeds if the following exists:

1. an acyclic connexion from `X0` to `X`, thus:

   `closure0(R_2, X0,X)` or more verbosely:

   `call(R_2, X0,X1), call(R_2, X1,X2), call(R_2, X2,X3), ..., call(R_2, Xn,X)`
   with `X0,X1,...,Xn` all pairwise different
2. one edge back

   `call(R_2, X,X0).`

so that is a cycle. In other words, a cyclic graph is a graph that contains at least one cycle. And that cycle consists of an acyclic part plus one edge back. And it is only this edge back that makes this a cycle.

Comment: Would you be able to explain whats going on this here?

Answer (score 0):

Your recursive predicate isConnected/2 misses the base case:

```
isConnected(X,Y) :- graph1(X,Y).
```

(assuming we are checking graph1, of course).

Anyway, you cannot use isConnected/2, since Prolog will loop on cyclic graphs.