# Determining if graph is connected in prolog

Tags: prolog, graph-traversal, transitive-closure, meta-predicate

I need to make a predicate `isConnected/1` that takes a graph as an argument and determines if there is an undirected path between the pairs.

Suppose I have a list of edges (where `G` is a graph):

```
isEdge(G,1,2).
isEdge(G,2,3).
isEdge(G,4,5).
```

So because there is no edge between 3 and 4 this should fail.
How would I approach this problem? Would I have to traverse though each edge and record the edges in a list? or is there a better approach to do this?

Comment: @false: the edge between 4 and 5 is on purpose to have a disconnected graph. btw, it's also an example of what closure0 should handle, but I can't see how it could be extended, without much complexity...

Comment: @CapelliC: I agree that my comment is ambiguous, I wanted to refer to what @ Sam said. Will rewrite it ..

Comment: [with clarification] "So because there is no edge between 3 and 4 this should fail." Why does there have to be an edge between 3 and 4? An edge between 5 and one of 1,2,3 would be just as good. Brief: it is not clear how you are defining the set of vertices.

Answer (score 2):

### Solution 1: Using a library

This is easy once you use a graph theory library. I'll first rewrite your graph using S-representation:

```
[1-[2],2-[1,3],3-[2],4-[5],5-[4]]
```

Then I'll use library `ugraph` included in SWI-Prolog ([thanks to Richard O'Keefe and Vitor Santos Costa](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=ugraphs)):

```
?- use_module(library(ugraph)).
?- G = [1-[2],2-[1,3],3-[2],4-[5],5-[4]], vertices(G, Vs), member(V, Vs), reachable(V, G, Ws).
G = [1-[2], 2-[1, 3], 3-[2], 4-[5], 5-[4]],
Vs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
V = 1,
Ws = [1, 2, 3] ;
G = [1-[2], 2-[1, 3], 3-[2], 4-[5], 5-[4]],
Vs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
V = 2,
Ws = [1, 2, 3] ;
G = [1-[2], 2-[1, 3], 3-[2], 4-[5], 5-[4]],
Vs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
V = 3,
Ws = [1, 2, 3] ;
G = [1-[2], 2-[1, 3], 3-[2], 4-[5], 5-[4]],
Vs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
V = 4,
Ws = [4, 5] ;
G = [1-[2], 2-[1, 3], 3-[2], 4-[5], 5-[4]],
Vs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
V = 5,
Ws = [4, 5].
```

### Solution 2: "Do it yourself"

Instead of relying on existing libraries, you can also implement this yourself in various ways (much recommended if you want to become a better programmer!). One way to implement this form the ground up is to use [closure0/3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26946133/definition-of-reflexive-transitive-closure)  which implements reflexive-transitive closure over a binary predicate (created by SO user *false*).

If you add the appropriate edges to your database:

```
edge(1,2).
edge(2,1).
edge(2,3).
edge(3,2).
edge(4,5).
edge(5,4).
```

... you can now query:

```
?- member(V, [1,2,3,4,5]), findall(W, closure0(edge, V, W), Ws).
V = 1,
Ws = [1, 2, 3] ;
V = 2,
Ws = [2, 1, 3] ;
V = 3,
Ws = [3, 2, 1] ;
V = 4,
Ws = [4, 5] ;
V = 5,
Ws = [5, 4].
```

Comment: It's `closure0/3` not `closure/3`! Please don't rename it!

Comment: @false Yup, altered my answer accordingly. Is the `0` suffix a convention of some kind / what does it mean?

Comment: `closure/3` is commonly the name for transitive closure, without the reflexive part.

Comment: Ah, so it's mainly to prevent interference with existing libraries. Plus the 0 may be taken to refer to the "reflexive closure"-part, i.e. a traversion of depth 0 in the graph.

Comment: The name would not fit. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15483764/772868) for `closure/3`. If you have a better name add it to my question.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that this is a followup to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26962312/prolog-determine-if-graph-is-acyclic):

First, you need to define what it means to be connected:

```
connected_to(R_2, A,B) :-
   (  call(R_2, A,B)
   ;  call(R_2, B,A)
   ).
```

Then you need to determine the set of nodes. Commonly the set of nodes is given, but it seems you want them being defined implicitly through all the edges:

```
rel_nodes(R_2, Nodes) :-
   setof(Node, Next^connected_to(R_2, Node,Next), Nodes).
```

Now being connected means that each node is connected to all other nodes.

```
is_connected(R_2) :-
   rel_nodes(R_2, Vs),
   maplist({R_2,Vs}+\V0^setof(V, closure0(connected_to(R_2), V0,V), Vs), Vs).
```

(All this assumes that the nodes are actually ground terms.)

Here are all the missing meta predicate declarations:

```
:- meta_predicate connected_to(2,?,?), rel_nodes(2,?), is_connected(2).
```