# Depth First Search Algorithm Prolog

Tags: algorithm, prolog, depth-first-search, transitive-closure

I am hoping you could help me with this.

I am trying to learn about Depth First search algorithm in Prolog and I have come across the following code

```
go(Start, Goal) :-
   empty_stack(Empty_been_list),
   stack(Start, Empty_been_list, Been_list),
   path(Start, Goal, Been_list).

% path implements a depth first search in PROLOG

% Current state = goal, print out been list
path(Goal, Goal, Been_list) :-
    reverse_print_stack(Been_list).

path(State, Goal, Been_list) :-
    mov(State, Next),
    % not(unsafe(Next)),
    not(member_stack(Next, Been_list)),
    stack(Next, Been_list, New_been_list),
    path(Next, Goal, New_been_list), !.

reverse_print_stack(S) :-
    empty_stack(S).
reverse_print_stack(S) :-
    stack(E, Rest, S),
    reverse_print_stack(Rest),
    write(E), nl.
```

I kind of understand what is going on, but I cant for the life of me find or invent some facts that I can use with it.

Please help. Even if its a really simple set of facts, I just need somewhere to start

Thank you in advance

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26946133/772868) is a generic solution to this problem. You simply say `closure0(mov,Start,Finis)`

Comment: Please indent `go` like the other predicates

Comment: I may have gone about asking the question the wrong way as I dont understand false' answer

Comment: @SeanGray: Provide the entire program - including some facts for `mov/2`. Without it, your code remains  hypothetical.

Comment: That is the question I am asking :D, I would like to know what facts I could use please.

Comment: Basically, you have no 'tree' to traverse.

Also, you have no implementation to the core predicates in your algorithm. Apparently, whoever thought of that was intending to use a stack and appropriate methods. I'd wager this is your homework to complete the gaps. Good luck

Answer (score 4):

The Following is an example of DFS used in prolog code

```js
% solve( Node, Solution):
%    Solution is an acyclic path (in reverse order) between Node and a goal

solve( Node, Solution)  :-
  depthfirst( [], Node, Solution).

% depthfirst( Path, Node, Solution):
%   extending the path [Node | Path] to a goal gives Solution

depthfirst( Path, Node, [Node | Path] )  :-
   goal( Node).

depthfirst( Path, Node, Sol)  :-
  s( Node, Node1),
  \+ member( Node1, Path),                % Prevent a cycle
  depthfirst( [Node | Path], Node1, Sol).

depthfirst2( Node, [Node], _)  :-
   goal( Node).

depthfirst2( Node, [Node | Sol], Maxdepth)  :-
   Maxdepth > 0,
   s( Node, Node1),
   Max1 is Maxdepth - 1,
   depthfirst2( Node1, Sol, Max1).


goal(f).
goal(j).
s(a,b).
s(a,c).
s(b,d).
s(b,e).
s(c,f).
s(c,g).
s(d,h).
s(e,i).
s(e,j).
```

In order to test this code head over to Swish SWI prolog and paste this into terminal.

Then query the code and type on right hand side: solve(a, Sol)

The solution will be: Sol = [j, e, b, a]

You can debug this code by typing: trace, (solve(a, Sol)).

The Following is an example of BFS used in prolog code

Head over to swish and query it using the same steps as before

The solution will be: Sol = [f, c, a]

```js
% solve( Start, Solution):
%    Solution is a path (in reverse order) from Start to a goal

solve( Start, Solution)  :-
  breadthfirst( [ [Start] ], Solution).

% breadthfirst( [ Path1, Path2, ...], Solution):
%   Solution is an extension to a goal of one of paths

breadthfirst( [ [Node | Path] | _], [Node | Path])  :-
  goal( Node).

breadthfirst( [Path | Paths], Solution)  :-
  extend( Path, NewPaths),
  append( Paths, NewPaths, Paths1),
  breadthfirst( Paths1, Solution).

extend( [Node | Path], NewPaths)  :-
  bagof( [NewNode, Node | Path],
         ( s( Node, NewNode), \+ member( NewNode, [Node | Path] ) ),
         NewPaths),
  !.

extend( Path, [] ).              % bagof failed: Node has no successor
s(a,b).
s(a,c).
s(b,d).
s(b,e).
s(c,f).
s(c,g).
s(d,h).
s(e,i).
s(e,j).
goal(j).
goal(f).
```

Hope this helps for understanding DFS and BFS

Use this diagram to help you understand the tree

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make facts that describe the valid moves in a graph.

So for instance, if you have nodes A, B, C, and D, every edge on the graph would have a mov() fact.  If A had edges to B and C, and B had an edge to D, your facts would be

```
mov(A, B).
mov(A, C).
mov(B, D).
```

Basically, draw a graph and write a fact like the above for every path from a node to another node.