# How to find useless states in a finite state machine Prolog

Tags: prolog, finite-automata, state-machine

I have been thinking of a solution for finding all the useless states defined in a particular automaton and I know that one approach is to start moving from the start state and then ask for the following state all of these stored in the Prolog predicate database. I have had no luck in writing the code very well because I am learning Prolog. I wish someone could help me out with this. Here I leave what I have.

The finite state machine structure. fa_start -> the initial state, fa_move -> the valid move from one state to another, fa_final -> the final state.

```
% Start State
:- assert(fa_start(fa_1, s_0)).
% Final States 
:- assert(fa_final(fa_1, s_5)).

:- assert(fa_move(fa_1, s_0, s_1, a)).
:- assert(fa_move(fa_1, s_1, s_4, b)).
:- assert(fa_move(fa_1, s_0, s_2, c)).
:- assert(fa_move(fa_1, s_2, s_4, d)).
:- assert(fa_move(fa_1, s_2, s_5, e)).
:- assert(fa_move(fa_1, s_0, s_3, f)).
:- assert(fa_move(fa_1, s_3, s_5, g)).
:- assert(fa_move(fa_1, s_6, s_3, h)).
:- assert(fa_move(fa_1, s_6, s_7, i)).
:- assert(fa_move(fa_1, s_7, s_8, j)).
```

Now, here is the code I have been writing. The idea is to start with `fa_start` and then keep moving using valid fa_move until it cannot reach `fa_final`.

```
adjacent(fa, N, M):-
   fa_move(fa, N, M, _).

adjacent_recursive(fa, N, L):-
   fa_start(fa, N),
   findall(l,adjacent(fa,N,_),L).

find_paths(fa):-
   adjacent_recursive(fa,s_0,_).
```

Thank you in advance for all the help.

Comment: What's your specific question? Note that `findall(l,adjacent(fa,N,_),L)` probably has a syntax error. `l` is an atom. Also, your queries to `fa_move` and `fa_start` all reference `fa`, but your facts use `fa_1`. So they'll never match.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for the notes. What I want is to print all useless states.

Comment: And, I have read the algorithm in [link](http://www.inrialpes.fr/vasy/people/Gordon.Pace/Research/Software/Relic/Transformations/FSA/remove-useless.html) but I don't know how to adapt it.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's difficult to find accurate information related to my specific question. I have been working on it and finally found a solution, may it not be the best, but makes the deal. I owe the idea to [this site](http://www.inrialpes.fr/vasy/people/Gordon.Pace/Research/Software/Relic/Transformations/FSA/remove-useless.html). If you find bugs, it'd be welcome.

Now, the following code prints the useless states given a finite state automata implemented as above.

```
find_useless_states(FA):- retractall(utiles(_)),retractall(visited(_)),
        forall(fa_final(FA,S),assert(utiles(S))),
        find_useless_states2(FA).
find_useless_states2(FA):- retract(utiles(S)),
     not(visited(S)), assert(visited(S)),
     forall((fa_move(FA,Y,S,_), not(visited(Y))),(asserta(utiles(Y)))),
     find_useless_states2(FA).
find_useless_states2(_).

difference(L1, L2, R) :- intersection(L1, L2, I),
                     append(L1, L2, All),
                     subtract(All, I, R).

find_all_states_as_list(FA,L):- findall(X,fa_move(FA,X,_,_),M),findall(Y,fa_move(FA,_,Y,_),N),merge(M,N,LL),sort(LL,L).
find_useful_states_as_list(L):- findall(X,visited(X),L).

print_useless_states(FA):- find_all_states_as_list(FA,L),find_useful_states_as_list(M), difference(L,M,R), length(R,D),write(R),nl,write(D).
```

Hope it helps other people. Some code ideas have been used from questions posted here in stackoverflow. I thank the people who answered those.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to use the dynamic database for all such things, but it easily gets very difficult to maintain. I'd rather compile the file with your definitions, thus avoid to perform `assertz/1` manually.

```
uselessstate(Aut, Usl) :-
   setof(S0, S^( closure0(adjacent(Aut), S0,S), fa_final(Aut,S) ), S0s),
   setof(t, A^B^( adjacent(Aut, A,B), (Usl=A;Usl=B) ), _),
   non_member(Usl, S0s).

unreachable(Aut, Usl) :-
   setof(S, S0^( fa_start(Aut, S0), closure0(adjacent(Aut), S0,S) ), Ss),
   setof(t, A^B^( adjacent(Aut, A,B), (Usl=A;Usl=B) ), _),
   non_member(Usl, Ss).
```

The [definition of `closure0/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26946133/772868) and `non_member/2` is found in another answer.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, too. Useless states are different from unreachable ones, but I was working on a solution to seek unreachable states also.