# Prolog: How do I return multiple values?

Tags: prolog

I want to take a value, such as 3 and return all from the given value to one.   For example, if I passed in count(3), I would get 3,2, 1 separately.  I don't want to return the values as a list.  For what  I wrote I tried to first return a value and then recursively call the next value to return.  This however only returns once.  What am I doing wrong?

```
 count(0,1).
 count(N,F) :-
      N1 is N-1,
      F is N-1,
      count(N1,F1).
```

Answer (score 1):

```
count(S0, S) :-
   closure0(\X0^X^succ(X,X0), S0, S).
```

using [this definition](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26946133/772868) and lambdas
or

```
count(N,N).
count(N0,N) :-
   succ(N1,N0),
   count(N1,N).
```

or in plain ISO Prolog:

```
count(N,N).
count(N0,N) :-
   N0 > 0,   % or 1
   N1 is N0-1,
   count(N1,N).
```

Comment: This returns values including 0, OP is asking to exclude 0.

Answer (score 0):

May be something like that :

```
 count(N,F) :-
    N > 0,
    (   F = N
    ;   N1 is N-1,
        count(N1,F)).
```

You get

> ?- count(3,V).
>
> V = 3 ;
>
> V = 2 ;
>
> V = 1 ;
>
> false.