# Prolog compiler return error

Tags: prolog, logic, prolog-toplevel, transitive-closure

I have this hypothetical program to check if a path exists from point A to B.

```
/*city rules*/

edge(phx, tuc).
edge(tuc, ccg).
edge(ccg, sf).

connected(C1, C2) :-
   edge(C1, C2).
connected(C1, C2) :- 
   edge(C1, X),
   connected(X, C2).
```

the problem is it returns true, then false. Where is the false coming from?

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at the exact reply you got from Prolog! First you got a single `true` and on pressing <kbd>SPACE</kbd> or <kbd>;</kbd> you eventually got:

```
?- connected(phx,sf).
   true
;  false.
```

So you got `true ; false.` as the complete answer. The `;` means "or". So Prolog essentially says: Your query `connected(phx,sf).` is the same as `true ; false.` So you need to look at the entire answer to understand what it means. Of course that is a bit odd, when `true.` would be good enough.

But first let's have another example:

```
?- connected(phx,X).
   X = tuc
;  X = ccg
;  X = sf
;  false.
```

Here Prolog's complete answer is: `connected(phx,X).` describes the same set of solutions as `X = tuc ; X = ccg ; X = fg ; false.` which again would be shorter if `false` would be omitted.

So why does Prolog write out this `false`? Prolog computes the answers incrementally. It first shows you `X = tuc` and waits what you would do. In a sense, it is a bit lazy not to show you everything at once. Sometimes, Prolog does know that there will be no further answer, in that case, it writes a dot directly:

```
?- member(X,[1,2]).
   X = 1
;  X = 2.
```

Here Prolog says: dixi! I have spoken.

But sometimes, it is not that sure:

```
?- member(1,[1,2]).
   true
;  false.
```

After proving that 1 is a member, it stops, otherwise it would have to explore the list further.

So this `; false.` means: After the last answer/solution, Prolog was not yet sure that everything has been explored. This might be an inefficiency, it might be an indication that something can be improved. However, **never, ever** take this as pretext to insert a cut into your program. The cut in another answer is completely malaprop. It is the source for many, many errors. Before starting to use cuts you really should learn the other, pure part of Prolog, first.

BTW: Here is a better definition for `connected/2` which avoids infinite loops by using [`closure/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26946133/772868) (click on it to get the definition).

```
connected(C0,C) :-
   edge(C0,C1)
   closure0(edge,C1,C).
```