# plan schedule based on flights cost

Tags: prolog

Suppose to have a list of air planes defined as follow:

```
plane(rome,berlin).
plane(berlin,london).
plane(london,lisboa).
plane(london,dublin).
plane(dublin,paris).
plane(rome,paris).
plane(berlin,paris).
```

I will solve the problem to find all routes between two cities in the following way:

```
route(Dep, Arr, [Dep, Arr]) :- plane(Dep, Arr).
route(Dep, Arr, [Dep|C]) :- plane(Dep, Z), route(Z, Arr, C).
```

For example with

```
?- route(rome,paris,P).
```

I obtain:

```
P = [rome, paris] 

P = [rome, berlin, paris] 

P = [rome, berlin, london, dublin, paris]
```

false.

The problem comes if I add prices, e.g.,

```
plane(rome,berlin,20).
plane(berlin,london,14).
plane(london,lisboa,44).
plane(london,dublin,99).
plane(dublin,paris,44).
plane(rome,paris,4).
plane(berlin,paris,6).
```

I have two questions:

- What does the last false represent?
- How can I get the list of all the routes with the total price and the cheaper one?

Comment: For `false`, look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27256298/772868)

Comment: Don't you get a `;` after `P = [rome, paris]` ? I really expect this to be there ...

Comment: I'm using swi-prolog, I get one solution at a time, and I press "space" to see all

Comment: In the versions of SWI I have, I see a `;` after each answer, even if I press SPACE to get the next answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, `false` means no more solutions were found.

To get the costs, you'll want to add the cost as an accumulator argument to your predicate to start with:

```
route(Dep, Arr, Route, Cost) :-
    route(Dep, Arr, Route, 0, Cost).
route(Dep, Arr, [Dep, Arr], AccCost, FinalCost) :-
    plane(Dep, Arr, Cost),
    FinalCost is AccCost + Cost.
route(Dep, Arr, [Dep|C], AccCost, FinalCost) :-
    plane(Dep, Z, Cost),
    NewCost is AccCost + Cost,
    route(Z, Arr, C, NewCost, FinalCost).
```

Then, `route(Dep, Arr, Route, Cost)` will generate each route in turn. If you want them in a list, you can do it with `setof/3`:

```
list_of_routes(Dep, Arr, Routes) :-
    setof(C-R, route(Dep, Arr, R, C), Routes).
```

This will yield a list of elements that look like `Cost-Route`, ordered by ascending `Cost`.

To get the cheapest route, pull off the first element of that list:

```
cheapest_route(Dep, Arr, Route, Cost) :-
    setof(C-R, route(Dep, Arr, R, C), [Cost-Route|_]).
```

Comment: What does C-R in setof stand for? I've seen setof with just 1 variable as first argument. I've tried to remove "-R" and I have the list of all the paths.

Comment: @newbie, All that does is create a Prolog *term*, `C-R` where `C` and `R` are variables. I could have used something like `foo(C,R)` or a little list, `[C,R]`. But I chose `C-R` since it is useful method of representing a pair of values. It's equivalent to the term, `'-'(C,R)`. So the `setof` collects all pairs of values of `C` and `R` and puts them in the form, `C-R` (note that you aren't limited to one variable in what you collect with `setof`). In Prolog, if you sort like terms, they go in order of the first argument, then the second, etc.

Comment: Thank you, how can that predicate be written in more comprensible way for prolog beginners like me?

Comment: You mean `list_of_routes`? It's not going to get much simpler since you're trying to collect, in a list, routes and associated cost. The cost is a number and the route is a list. You'd need to choose a way to represent those together (I chose `C-R`, but, as I mentioned, you can use `[C,R]` or `cost_route(C,R)` or just `(C,R)`...) and that will have to be part of the `setof` call. For example, using `cost_route(C,R)` would look like, `list_of_routes(Dep, Arr, Routes) :- setof(cost_route(C,R), route(Dep, Arr, R, C), Routes).`