# Monkey & Banana in prolog

Tags: prolog

I have this prolog code for solving monkey and banana problem but my compiler give an error

This is my code:

```
move(state(middle, onbox, middle, hasnot), grasp,
     state(middle, onbox, middle, has)).
move(state(Pos, onfloor, Pos, Has), climb,
     state(Pos, onbox, Pos, Has)).
move(state(Pos1, onfloor, Pos1, Has), push(Pos1, Pos2),
     state(Pos2, onfloor, Pos2, Has)).
move(state(Pos1, onfloor, Box, Has), walk(Pos1, Pos2),
     state(Pos2, onfloor, Box, Has)).

canget(state(_,_,_,has)).
canget(State1) :- move(State1, Move, State2), canget(State2).
```

Error: Move is Singleton Variable.
What is my wrong?

Comment: "Singleton" means that you used a named variable only once in the lexical scope of a predicate clause. So, this variable is "ignored", and not used in any way in this clause, hence the warning.

Answer (score 1):

```
canget(S0) :-
   S = state(_,_,_,has),
   closure0(\X^Y^move(X,_,Y),S0,S).
```

Using [`closure0/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26946133/772868) and [lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/prolog+lambda)