# Prolog Out of local stack error

Tags: prolog, transitive-closure

I tried some basic example from a book and it makes "Out of local stack" error (I'll tell more after the code).
here is the code:

```
edge(a,b).
edge(a,e).
edge(b,d).
edge(b,c).
edge(c,a).
edge(e,b).
tedge(Node1,Node2) :-
    edge(Node1,SomeNode),
    edge(SomeNode,Node2).
edge(X,Y) :- tedge(X,Y).
```

I tried for example to write query edge(a,b) and it returned true and then I entered ';' and it made the error. 
What's the problem here?

Comment: The short answer is that it went into infinite recursion. If you do a `trace`, you'll see what's happening. Why did you defined `edge(X,Y) :- tedge(X,Y).`? It's bound to create a loop scenario since `edge/2` also defines facts which `tedge/2` refers to. Just leave it at `tedge/2` and query `tedge(a,b).`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you have defined what an edge is in a cyclic way. While looking for a second path from `a` to `b` Prolog is looping through `tedge(a,VAR)`, `edge(a,VAR)`, `tedge(a,VAR)`, etc.

Notice that Prolog would loop even if you had not defined your edges to be symmetric, namely due to the cycle `a -> b -> c -> a`.

The solution is to keep track of vertices and/or edges that have been visited before. Checking for non-recurring vertices can be straightforwardly implemented using [closure0/3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26946133/definition-of-reflexive-transitive-closure) (a predicate I learned from SO user false). If you use that predicate, you only need your `edge/2` facts and the following query:

```
?- closure0(edge, a, b).
```

Comment: What a luxury, I need no longer type in answers!