# getting out of local stack at prolog

Tags: prolog, transitive-closure

```
p(0,0).
p(0,1).
p(0,2).
p(0,3).
p(0,4).
p(1,1).
p(1,2).
p(1,3).
p(1,4).
p(1,0).
p(2,0).
p(2,1).
p(2,2).
p(2,3).
p(2,4).
p(3,0).
p(3,1).
p(3,2).
p(3,3).
p(3,4).
p(4,0).
p(4,1).
p(4,2).
p(4,3).
p(4,4).

adjacent(p(X,Y),p(X,Z)) :-
    p(X,Y),
    p(X,Z),
    Z is Y+1.
adjacent(p(X,Y),p(X,Z)) :-
    p(X,Y),
    p(X,Z),
    Z is Y-1.
adjacent(p(X,Y),p(Z,Y)) :-
    p(X,Y),
    p(X,Z),
    Z is X+1.
adjacent(p(X,Y),p(Z,Y)) :-
    p(X,Y),
    p(X,Z),
    Z is X-1.

adjacentC(X,Y) :-
    adjacent(X,Y).
adjacentC(X,Y) :-
    adjacent(X,Z),
    adjacentC(Z,Y).
```

I don't know why this code I wrote isn't working.

e.g.:

```
?- adjacentC((0,0),(4,4)). ERROR
```

Comment: What is it supposed to do?

Comment: it supposed to find a path between pair of points. :/

Comment: What does the error say? Does it just say "ERROR"? Did you try tracing the execution to make sure the program does what you think it does (obviously, it doesn't....)

Comment: ive found the problem. im using the adjacent predicate wrong, i want adjacent(p(0,0),X) to return facts EG:   (0,1) and (1,0)

Answer (score 1):

Quick answer: The following works and terminates always using [`closure/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26946133/772868) defined elsewhere.

```
adjacentD(X,Y) :-
   closure(adjacent,X,Y).
```

However, this approach is extremely slow, due to the inefficient definition of `adjacent/3`. Here is a better one / oh forget it, here is a more correct one, first:

```
adjacent2(p(X0,Y0),p(X,Y)) :-
   p(X0,Y0),
   (  X0 = X,
      p(X,Y),
      abs(Y0-Y) =:= 1
   ;  Y0 = Y,
      p(X,Y),
      abs(X0-X) =:= 1
   ).
```