# Prolog- singleton variable in branch warning

Tags: variables, prolog, singleton

Hello here is my code in Prolog:

```
arc(a,h).
arc(b,c).

related_to(X, Ys) :-
   setof(Y, arc(X, Y), Ys).

cut([H|T],Y) :- 
    check(H,Y),

    T = [] ->   cut(T,Y).

check(X,Y) :-
    related_to(X,Xs),
    member(Y,Xs) ->  write('There is a road');
    cut(Xs,Y).
```

When I am trying to run `check(a,b)` it doesn't run. I get the message

```
Singleton variable in branch: Xs
```

When I am not using cut question, I don't get any error. I would be grateful for pointing me where I made a mistake and showing way to repair it.

Comment: In the code you show, I don't see a singleton variable issue. And `check(a,b)` runs forever (doesn't terminate). Is the code you are showing what you actually ran? Did you try doing a `trace` to see what's happening?

Comment: Also, be wary of operator precedence. `,` has higher precedence than `;`. In your `check` code, it is equivalent to `check(X,Y) :- (related_to(X,Xs), member(Y,Xs) -> write('There is a road')) ; cut(Xs, Y).` So if `related_to(X,Xs)` fails, then it will call `cut(Xs,Y)` with `Xs` unbound.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Prolog is right. And you really are doing the best taking the messages seriously.

You are using if-then-else in an unconventional manner. For this reason it is not that simple to figure out what is happening. When I say `listing(check)` I get the following:

```
check(A, B) :-
        (   related_to(A, C),
            member(B, C)
        ->  write('There is a road')
        ;   cut(C, B)
        ).
```

So Prolog was not very impressed by your indentation style, instead, it just looked for operators. In fact, the `C` (which is your original `Xs`) occurs in the if-part which is unrelated to the else-part. What you probably wanted is:

```
check(X,Y) :-
    related_to(X,Xs),
    (  member(Y,Xs)
    -> write('There is a road')
    ;  cut(Xs,Y)
    ).
```

Regardless of the concrete problem at hand, I very much doubt that your code makes sense: `Xs` is a list of connected nodes, but do you really need this **in this context**? I do not think so.

Why not use [`closure0/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26946133/772868) to determine connectedness:

```
?- closure0(arc, A, B).
```

BTW, it is not clear whether you consider a directed graph or an undirected one. Above works only for directed graphs, for undirected graphs rather use:

```
comm(P_2, A,B) :-
   (  call(P_2, A,B)
   ;  call(P_2, B,A)
   ).
?- closure0(comm(arc), A, B).
```

If you are interested in the path as well, use [`path/4`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30328433/772868):

```
?- path(comm(arc), Path, A, B).
```

Comment: i want to implement direct graph :)

Comment: @SzymonSutek: Then leave out the `comm`

Comment: thank u, it is working now. I have one problem. When i check for a correct road i am getting:  There is a roadFalse. How to avoid printing false?

Comment: `false` is the answer to say: There is no solution.

Comment: Generally speaking: It does not make much sense to add side-effectful built-ins like `write/` into many programs. Better describe clean relations.