# How to make a condition to end the query in prolog?

Tags: prolog

i'm new in prolog, so i have done a program which have a method to query something, but when i use it, it keeps yielding results even when it should end.

```
amigos(juanarjona,omarpacheco).
amigos(juanarjona,jasonancona).
amigos(juanarjona,jorgebolio).
amigos(juanarjona,gerardoadrian).

amigos(Amigo,Amigoslista):-!,amigos(Amigoslista,Amigo).
```

for example, when i execute

```
amigos(X,juanarjona).
```

it should give me just this answers:

> X = omarpacheco ; X = jasonancona ; X = jorgebolio ; X = gerardoadrian
>   ;

but what it really do is to repeat those answers without end like this

> X = omarpacheco ; X = jasonancona ; X = jorgebolio ; X = gerardoadrian
>   ; X = omarpacheco ; X = jasonancona ; X = jorgebolio ; X =
>   gerardoadrian . . . . . . . . . . . . (repeating)...........

so, that's why i'm recurring to you guys, i need to know how to establish a condition which do not let repeating the answers.
Sorry for my bad english by the way.

**I Forgot to say that it must be with just one predicate in this case "amigos"**

Comment: Please be more specific! What about other limitations of what you may or may not use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's easy: Use **two** predicates instead of one!

The first predicate comprises facts only:

```
amigos(juanarjona, omarpacheco).
amigos(juanarjona, jasonancona).
amigos(juanarjona, jorgebolio).
amigos(juanarjona, gerardoadrian).
```

The second one—built on top of the first one—provides the symmetric closure<sup>1</sup>:

```
sym_amigos(X, Y) :- amigos(X, Y).
sym_amigos(X, Y) :- amigos(Y, X).
```

Sample query using SICStus Prolog 4.3.2:

```
| ?- sym_amigos(P, Q).
P = juanarjona,    Q = omarpacheco   ? ;
P = juanarjona,    Q = jasonancona   ? ;
P = juanarjona,    Q = jorgebolio    ? ;
P = juanarjona,    Q = gerardoadrian ? ;
P = omarpacheco,   Q = juanarjona    ? ;
P = jasonancona,   Q = juanarjona    ? ;
P = jorgebolio,    Q = juanarjona    ? ;
P = gerardoadrian, Q = juanarjona    ? ;
no
```

As your fact base gets larger and larger, looking at all the concrete answers gets tiresome... So, to check if `sym_amigos/2` *terminates universally*, we can run a query like this one:

```
| ?- sym_amigos(P, Q),      % looking for amigos ...
     false.                 % ... we discard every candidate solution.
no                          % "no" means "terminates universally"
```

Above query can never yield any solution—after all, it is a conjunction with the goal `false/0`:

- It **can**, however, tell us if the above goal terminates universally.
- If Prolog returns `no`—it does<sup>2</sup>—we know that `sym_amigos/2` terminates universally.

---

<sup>**Footnote 1:**
[meta-predicate](/questions/tagged/meta-predicate)  [`symm/2`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31405602/4609915) covers the common idiom "[symmetric closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_closure)".


**Footnote 2:** SWI-Prolog does not reply `no` but `false` instead.</sup>