# prolog out of local stack

Tags: prolog, stack-overflow, stack-trace

Don't need answer anymore. its done. Thanks !

```
a(S,E,[S|R]) :- S\=E,(c(S, N);c(N,S)),a(N,E,R),\+member(S,R).
a(X,X,P):- P=[X].
```

The above code cause out of local stack problem, Could someone tell me how to fix? Thanks.

Comment: c(1,2). 
c(1,3).c(2,4).c(3,4).

Comment: `A(S,E,[S|R]) :- ...` isn't valid Prolog syntax, so I doubt the code you are showing even executed. It would have thrown an error. Please show the code you actually tried.

Comment: I am so sorry, I mean a instead of A. Since Im asking a homework problem, to avoid showing answer online, I changed all the names and I made a horrible mistake. Thank you guys for pointing out

Comment: Work harder on improving the quality of your question! Use proper code layout. Choose proper names. Write the queries you did, the answer(s) you expected and the answer(s) you got.

Comment: You should accept the answer given by @CapelliC if you found it acceptable. There's a checkmark that you click when viewing his answer. It's very unorthodox to edit your question to say it's answered. That should be evident from accepting the appropriate answer. Also, others may still want to offer answers just as useful alternatives or more information, if not for you, then for others reading the question and answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To complete a visit of a graph with loops (introduced in your DAG from `c(S, N);c(N,S)`), we must check the path seen *so far* (just to say), but you attempt to inspect *after* it has been built. This 'logical loop' reflects in non termination of your code. The easier solution is to add an argument that holds the path seen so far:

```
a(S,E,P) :- visit(S,E,[S],P).

visit(X,X,P,R) :- reverse(P,R).
visit(S,E,P,R) :- (c(S,N);c(N,S)), \+memberchk(N,P), visit(N,E,[N|P],R).
```

yields

```
?- a(1,4,L).
L = [1, 2, 4] ;
L = [1, 3, 4] ;
false.
```

see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26946133/definition-of-reflexive-transitive-closure) about some high level thoughts on this theme

Comment: you are amazing, it works. And if I try more complicated graph, it may give me same answer twice. Do you know why? And thank you !

Comment: for example,i have c(10,14) and c(14,10). When it done with using (10,14), next time it will use (14,10). That is why I get same answer. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: @SwordW. How about accepting this answer by CapelliC as a sign of gratitude? And while we're at it... Please improve the quality of your question, so it becomes more approachable by others interested in it in the future: add all relevant code parts (not into a comment to your own question, but to the **question itself**). use proper code layout. add queries (and their respective answers) you have tried for testing, so others can reproduce the problem you were having.