# Define a transitive relation over facts

Tags: prolog, transitive-closure

I am new to Prolog and trying to learn it.
I want to achieve something like `a>b` and `b>c` then `a>c` which is Transitive relation.

I have a set of following rules.

```
bigger(elephant,horse).
bigger(horse,ant).
bigger(ant, bacteria).
bigger(bacteria,virus).
```

We know that elephant is bigger than virus. What I want to achieve is that when I use `smaller(ant,elephant)` it should return `true`. The rule `smaller(X,Y)` I tried to use is

```
smaller(Y,X) :-
    bigger(X,Z),
   (bigger(Z,Y);
    Z=Y).
```

Comment: See [tag:transitive-closure], and specifically the [definition](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26946133/1613573).

Comment: @lurker that is working because it's the second rule and doesn't work for `smaller(virus,elephant)`

Comment: As @mat points out, you need transitive closure. So if you break it into two clauses, you'd have: `smaller(X, Y) :- bigger(Y, X).` and `smaller(X, Y) :- bigger(Z, X), smaller(Z, Y).`

Comment: But that gives out two responses `true` and `false`

Comment: The first result `true` means it succeeded in the query for the first result. The subsequent `false` means it didn't find any more solutions (there was a choice point).

Comment: Got it, and are there any good books or tutorials to learn Prolog from

Comment: Several good books. *The Art of Prolog* by Sterling & Shapiro, *The Craft of Prolog* by O'Keefe, *Programming in Prolog* by Clocksin & Mellish. There are some online tutorials which are fairly basic, but you can learn some things from them. Just Google "Prolog tutorial".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can perhaps use `big_fact/2` to describe the database:

```
big_fact(elephant,horse).
big_fact(horse,ant).
big_fact(ant, bacteria).
big_fact(bacteria,virus).
```

Then you can use `bigger/2` as a transitive closure:

```
bigger(X,Y) :-
    big_fact(X,Y).
bigger(X,Z) :-
    big_fact(X,Y),
    bigger(Y,Z).
```

If you run this in [swi-prolog](/questions/tagged/swi-prolog), it generates:

```
?- bigger(X,Y).
X = elephant,
Y = horse ;
X = horse,
Y = ant ;
X = ant,
Y = bacteria ;
X = bacteria,
Y = virus ;
X = elephant,
Y = ant ;
X = elephant,
Y = bacteria ;
X = elephant,
Y = virus ;
X = horse,
Y = bacteria ;
X = horse,
Y = virus ;
X = ant,
Y = virus ;
false.

?- bigger(virus,Y).
false.

?- bigger(ant,Y).
Y = bacteria ;
Y = virus ;
false.

?- bigger(X,horse).
X = elephant ;
false.

?- bigger(X,bacteria).
X = ant ;
X = elephant ;
X = horse ;
false.

?- bigger(elephant,bacteria).
true ;
false.
```

So it is a *transitive closure*.

You can then define `smaller/2` by means of `bigger/2`:

```
smaller(X,Y) :-
    bigger(Y,X).
```