# Prolog transitive closure: maze pathfinder

Tags: prolog, transitive-closure

I'm interested in implementing a simple Prolog program that performs path finding queries on maze structures.

```
/* i_ -> intersections  */
i_(c,b). /* horizontal adjacencies */
i_(g,h).
i_(h,i).
i_(i,g).
i_(a,d). /* vertical adjacencies */
i_(d,g).
i_(c,f).
i_(f,i).

/* symmetric interface */
i(X,Y) :- i_(X,Y);i_(Y,X).

/* path, the rule in question*/
path(X,Y) :- i(X,Y) ; i(X,Z), path(Z,Y).
```

Bug: My Prolog interpreter (SWI) is thrown into a state of infinite recursion when path is used with input nodes >= 5 steps away.
However, the rule works fine with fewer than 5 nodes step in path. Curiously,omitting the rule of symmetry (simply declaring each adjacency, backwards and forwards), reduces the call limit of path to fewer than 3 nodes difference. Overriding the default stack allocation again increases the span of path before stack overflow.

Obviously, an accumulator is in order. I suspect that my program crashes at run time because the interpreter continues to revisit nodes already traversed in the path.

I modified `path` to include an additional requirement of `legal`, which serves as an accumulator:

```
/* path --> recursive path check */
legal(Z,[]).
legal(Z,[H|T]):- Z\==H, legal(Z,T). 
path(X,Y,T) :- i(X,Y) ; i(X,Z), legal(Z,T), path(Z,Y,[Z|T]).
```

However, I'm now facing an issue with the var `Z` as a 'singleton'.

Any suggestions as to how I can properly implement a accumulator so as to avoid excessive stack calls?

Comment: `path(X,Y) :- closure0(i,X,Y).` See the definition of [`closure0/3`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26946133).

Comment: Using SWI-Prolog, the following error occurred: ?- path(a,b).                                                                                
ERROR: path/2: Undefined procedure: closure0/3                                               
   Exception: (7) closure0(i, a, b) ? Unknown option (h for help)                            
   Exception: (7) closure0(i, a, b) ? creep

Comment: @DavidShaked the definition of `closure0/3` is given in the link that false shows. It's not in the SWI library.

Comment: Hi, David! I believe we talked about this briefly the other night at the N-Languages meetup. The `Singleton variables` warning is only alerting you to the fact that, in the clause `legal(Z,[]).`, the variable `Z` appears only once. This warning helps catch a lot of bugs caused by typos (where one variable ends up slightly misnamed). Usually, when you don't need a variable again in the same clause, you leave it anonymous: `legal(_,[]).`, then you won't receive that (harmless) warning.

Comment: @ShonFeder Not really that harmless, or rather, in this case harmless, but you explain yourself why it should definitely not be ignored.

Comment: @ShonFeder Great to hear from you! I put your anon var suggestion to use in place of Z and compiled without a problem. I'll run more tests when I get a chance to ensure the program is behaving as expected. Thanks for the pointer!