# Add loop edges in datalog (bddbddb)

Tags: graph-theory, identity, datalog, transitive-closure

I have the following rules that find all the paths among a graph.

```
path(X,Y) :- edge(X,Y).
path(X,Y) :- edge(X,Z), path(Z,Y).
```

But, I want also **for each node n**, to **add the edge n->n** if not already present.

How can I do this without having any relation of the nodes?

Answer (score 3):

In Prolog alone, you would write:

```
path(X,X).
path(X,Y) :- false, edge(X,Y).
path(X,Y) :- edge(X,Z), path(Z,Y).
```

or somewhat shorter and more terminating using [`closure0/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26946133).

```
path(X,Y) :-
   closure0(edge, X,Y).
```

In (many definitions of) Datalog as a subset of Prolog, facts like `path(X,X).` are not permitted, since they admit an infinite set of solutions.

So you need to restrict that fact to a finite set of nodes. However, since you do not have an explicit definition of nodes, you need to make up one based on the edges you have:

```
node(X) :-
   edge(X,_).
node(Y) :_
   edge(_,Y).
```

which now leads to:

```
path(X,X) :-
   node(X).
path(X,Y) :-
   edge(X,Z),
   path(Z,Y).
```

Comment: Error on line :
'path(X,X) :- node(X).'
                      ^
Variable repeated multiple times in a single term

Comment: emma: So you are really using another system, and this is entirely unrelated to Prolog. You should indicate the name of this system in your question.

Comment: It's the datalog language of bddbddb system. Is it so different?!

Comment: @emma: Yes. It is a "subset" of Prolog only in a very, very special sense.