# Prolog recursive accumulator

Tags: recursion, prolog, accumulator

I am trying to make a knowledge base for college courses. Specifically, right now I am trying to make an accumulator that will take a course and provide a list of all classes that must be taken first, i.e. The course's prereqs, the prereqs to those prereqs, etc... [Based on this chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5AzbU.png).

Here is a sample of the predicates:

```
prereq(cst250, cst126).
prereq(cst223, cst126).
prereq(cst126, cst116).
prereq(cst105, cst102).
prereq(cst250, cst130).
prereq(cst131, cst130).
prereq(cst130, cst162).
prereq(anth452, wri122).
prereq(hist452, wri122).
```

And here is my attempt at an accumulator:

```
prereq_chain(Course, PrereqChain):-
    %Get the list of prereqs for Course
    findall(Prereq, prereq(Course, Prereq), Prereqs),

    %Recursive call to all prereqs in X
    forall(member(X, Prereqs),
           (prereq_chain(X, Y),    
            %Combine current layer prereqs with deeper
            append(Prereqs, Y, Z))),

    %Return PrereqChain
    PrereqChain = Z.
```

The desired output from a query would be:

```
?- prereq_chain(cst250, PrereqList).
PrereqList = [cst116, cst126, cst162, cst130]
```

Instead, I get an answer of true, and a warning about Z being a singleton.

I have looked at [other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37067612/prolog-recursion-and-accumulators) asking on similar issues, but they all had a single lane of backward traversal, whereas my solution requires multiple lanes.

Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Comment: For an accumulator you need two parameters (in & out). Start with writing a predicate `requires/2` that just takes two courses and succeeds if the 1st one requires the 2nd (or generates all the required courses).

Comment: Thank you Tomas - I may have gone about it the wrong way. I'll try this approach.

Comment: Tomas: I think actually, I already have that predicate: prereq(CourseA, CourseB), which I make use of. It does work for a single layer of prereqs, but my trouble lies in the recursive calls feeding to the list.

Comment: Yes, you need a recursive call (but no higher order stuff).

Comment: You have two real problems. The first is that the scope of `Z` inside the body of the `forall/2` is hidden from the outer scope where you need it. The deeper problem is that you are thinking procedurally by trying to modify Prereqs by adding stuff to it in your `forall/2` call. The final assignment of `PrereqChain = Z` is harmless but demonstrates that you're still thinking procedurally; if you instead just had `append(Prereqs, Y, PrereqChain)` and no final line, the meaning would be the same and the problem might be more obvious.

Comment: Thank you Daniel - that does explain the singleton warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with using `forall/2` is that it does not establish bindings. Look at this contrived example:

```
?- forall(member(X, [1,2,3]), append(['hi'], X, R)).
true.
```

If a binding were established for X or R by the `forall/2`, it would appear in the result; instead we just got `true` because it succeeded. So you need to use a construct that doesn't just run some computation but something that will produce a value. The thing you want in this case is `maplist/3`, which takes a goal and a list of parameters and builds a larger goal, giving you back the results. You will be able to see the effect in your console after you put in the solution below.

```
?- maplist(prereq_chain, [cst126, cst130], X).
X = [[cst116], [cst162]].
```

So this went and got the list of prerequisites for the two classes in the list, but gave us back a list of lists. This is where `append/2` comes in handy, because it essentially flattens a list of lists:

```
?- append([[cst116], [cst162]], X).
X = [cst116, cst162].
```

Here's the solution I came up with:

```
prereq_chain(Class, Prereqs) :-
    findall(Prereq, prereq(Class, Prereq), TopPrereqs),
    maplist(prereq_chain, TopPrereqs, MorePrereqs),
    append([TopPrereqs|MorePrereqs], Prereqs).
```

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you so much for the explanation!

Comment: @Ethan no problem :)

Comment: @Ethan can you click the check to accept the answer?