# (Prolog) How to find if a connection exists between 2 predicates

Tags: prolog, transitive-closure

This is what I have so far. I need to show that if two stations are connected via a third station, they are connected to each other

```
station(hamburg).
station(bremen).
station(hannover).
station(berlin).
station(leipzig).
station(osnabruck).
station(stuttgart).
station(fulda).
station(munich).

adjacent(hamburg, bremen).
adjacent(hamburg, berlin).
adjacent(berlin, hannover).
adjacent(berlin, leipzig).
adjacent(leipzig, fulda).
adjacent(fulda, hannover).
adjacent(hannover, osnabruck).
adjacent(osnabruck, bremen).
adjacent(stuttgart, munich).

/* insert your clauses here */

adjacent_(X,Y) :-adjacent(Y,X) .
adjacent_(X,Y) :-adjacent(X,Y) .

connected(X,Y) :-adjacent(X,Y) .
connected(X,Z) :-connected(X,Y), adjacent_(Y,Z) .
```

Comment: Using [`closure/3`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26946133/772868): `connected(X, Y) :- closure(adjacent_, X, Y).`

Answer (score 0):

Your first `connected` clause will fail for a clause like:

```
?- connected(bremen, hamburg).
```

Presumably you meant to write

```
connected(X,Y) :- adjacent_(X,Y) .
```

instead.

Other than the above bug, your code seems fine. The only thing I'd add is that you're not guarding against "cycles". E.g. if you were trying to find if berlin is connected to fulda, in theory you might never get there because of the following cycle:

> **berlin** -> **hannover** -> **osnabruck** -> **bremen** -> **hamburg** -> **berlin** (and so on ad infinitum).

Therefore you could also include an accumulator in your code, containing all the nodes visited so far, such that you don't allow your clause to succeed if the current node already appears in your node "path".

---

<sub>PS. If you're only interested to find out whether X and Z are connected, and not in how many possible ways, you could also explicitly specify a cut (i.e. `!`) at the end of each `connected` clause.</sub>

Comment: Thanks, @false . I admit I can't see how that occurs and why the above `adjacent_` mitigates that problem. Do you mind explaining?

Comment: See [tag:failure-slice].

Comment: Thanks, I see it now and feeling kinda stupid for not seeing it straightaway :p I'll edit my answer accordingly.