# Prolog: check transitivity for simple facts

Tags: prolog, predicate, failure-slice, transitive-closure, transitivity

My intention was to implement a simple example (just for myself) of transitivity in Prolog.

These are my facts:

```
trust_direct(p1, p2).
trust_direct(p1, p3).
trust_direct(p2, p4).
trust_direct(p2, p5).
trust_direct(p5, p6).
trust_direct(p6, p7).
trust_direct(p7, p8).
trust_direct(p100, p200).
```

I've written this predicate to check whether `A` trusts `C`, which is true whenever there is a `B` that trusts `C` and `A` trusts this `B`:

```
trusts(A, B) :-
    trust_direct(A, B).

trusts(A, C) :-
    trusts(A, B),
    trusts(B, C).
```

The predicate returns `true` for `trusts(p1, p2)` or `trusts(p1, p5)` for example, but `trusts(p5, p6)` already returns `ERROR: Out of local stack`.

Is Prolog flooding the stack this quickly?

Or is my idea/implementation of `trusts` bad / wasting system memory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes**, Prolog is flooding the local stack this quickly.

To see this, it suffices to *only* consider the following program fragment:

```
trusts(A, C) :-
        trusts(A, B),
        false,
        trusts(B, C).
```

This is called a [failure-slice](/questions/tagged/failure-slice): I have inserted `false/0`, so that everything after `false/0` **can be ignored**. I indicate parts that can be ignored with <s>strikeout</s> text.

This means that the snippet is actually equivalent to:

```
trusts(A, C) :-
        trusts(A, B),
        false.
```

Now, with either of the above snippets, we immediately get:

```
?- trusts(p5, p6).
ERROR: Out of local stack
```

To get rid of this problem, you **have to change the remaining fragment**. For this reason, such a fragment serves as an **explanation** of the problem.

For example, consider the following version:

```
trusts(A, B) :-
        trust_direct(A, B).
trusts(A, C) :-
        trust_direct(A, B),
        trusts(B, C).
```

Sample query:

```
?- trusts(p5, p6).
true ;
false.
```

This now works as expected. It is declaratively equivalent to the version you posted, and has much better termination properties:

```
?- trusts(X, Y), false.
false.
```

This shows that the program now **terminates universally**.

Alternative solutions are:

- use your Prolog system's **tabling** facilities
- use the definition of [**transitive closure**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26946133/definition-of-reflexive-transitive-closure)
- etc.

Comment: Nice explanation! However, I've got one last question: if we already have `trusts(A, C) :- trust_direct(A, B), trusts(B, C)` (the call to `trust_direct/2`), why do we need the second `trusts(A, B) :- trust_direct(A, B).`?

Comment: That's a great question, and very much worth posting on its own! Please file a new question for this, and let us continue there!

Comment: Here it is: [Unnecessary predicate definition for simple transitivity checkup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42496415/unnecessary-predicate-definition-for-simple-transitivity-checkup)