# Unnecessary predicate definition for simple transitivity checkup?

Tags: prolog, transitivity

For the given facts:

```
trust_direct(p1, p2).
trust_direct(p1, p3).
trust_direct(p2, p4).
trust_direct(p2, p5).
trust_direct(p5, p6).
trust_direct(p6, p7).
trust_direct(p7, p8).
trust_direct(p100, p200).
```

This solution:

```
trusts(A, B) :-
        trust_direct(A, B).
trusts(A, C) :-
        trust_direct(A, B),
        trusts(B, C).
```

...was given to improve my stack overflow issue described in [Prolog: check transitivity for simple facts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42495922/prolog-check-transitivity-for-simple-facts#42496038).

The solution itself works like a charm. However, I am confused by the doubled `trust_direct(A, B)`. Why is this necessary?

Shouldn't the `trusts(A, C)` predicate already cover the `trust_direct(A, B)` relationship?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26946133/772868) generic definition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a great question!

To show the reason for this, I use the following definition to enable **declarative debugging**:

> ```
> :- op(950,fy, *).
>
> *_.
> ```

I can now put `*` in front of any goal to **generalize it away**. Declaratively, this means that I can simply *ignore* the goal (recall that a goal is always a *constraint*, restricting any solution). I could of course also simply *comment* goals away, but that does not work nicely for the *last* goal of a clause body.

Now consider your definition:

```
trusts(A, B) :-
        trust_direct(A, B).
trusts(A, C) :-
        trust_direct(A, B),
        trusts(B, C).
```

Now, to answer your very legitimate question, suppose we *only* had the second clause, i.e.:

```
trusts(A, C) :-
        trust_direct(A, B),
        trusts(B, C).
```

To make our life simpler, I now **generalize** this definition as follows:

```
trusts(A, C) :-
        * trust_direct(A, B),
        trusts(B, C).
```

This is *more general* than the immediately preceding snippet: *If* `trusts(X, Y)` holds for any `X` and `Y` with the preceding snippet, then `trusts(X, Y)` *also* holds with this definition.

I have used <s>strikeout</s> text to indicate goals that are not relevant (because they are generalized away). So, this is declaratively equivalent to:

```
trusts(A, C) :-
        trusts(B, C).
```

Let us read this *declaratively*:

> `trusts(A, C)` holds **if** `trusts(B, C)` holds.

But *when* does `trusts(B, C)` hold? Of course (by simply applying the definition again), **if** `trusts(B', C')` holds. And *when* does this hold? Of course (by simply applying the definition), **if** ... etc. From here, it is easy to see that we will *never* find any `A` and `C` so that `trusts(A, C)` holds *at all*.

And that *despite* the fact that this is actually the *significantly more general* version of the original clause! Thus, there is not the slightest hope to satisfy the *more specific* version!

This answers our question: We need a case that **actually holds**, and what could be simpler than talking about `trust_direct/2`, which is really the simplest case in which we definitely *expect* the more general relation `trusts/2` to hold **too**.

It is thus very natural to start with this case, and say:

> **If** `trust_direct(X, Y)` holds **then** `trusts(X, Y)` holds.

In Prolog:

```
trusts(X, Y) :- trust_direct(X, Y).
```

And that's exactly your first clause!