# Prolog, find friend of friend

Tags: prolog

I'm new to Prolog. I'm trying to write a query to check if a person is the friend or friend of friend of another person.

I have some facts like this:

```
friends(joe, [john, ann, pete, ellen, 
          maria, jose, bruno, ali, jing, yang]).
friends(john, [rick]).
friends(ellen, [mia, xing, jun, maria]).
friends(maria, [pete, ellen, zhang, jose, serena]).
friends(serena, [ali, rick, zhang, mia]).
friends(jose, [maria, jose, bruno, ali, jing]).
```

My target is to write a query like this:

```
visible(joe, ann).
true
```

I have made something like this:

```
visible(X,Y) :- friends(X,[Y|T]); member(Y,T).
visible(X,Y) :- visible(X,Z), visible(Z,Y).

member(X,[X|T]). 
member(X,[H|T]) :- member(X,T).
```

But it becomes an infinite loop. I don't know how to write the base case.

The relationship is a graph with loop. Is there anyway to recursively find the friend of friend, transitively?

Comment: `friend(X, Y) :- friends(X,Ys), member(Y,Ys).` and `visible(X, Y) :- closure(friend, X, Y).` using [this definition](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26946133/772868).

Comment: I got this error: ERROR: Undefined procedure: closure/3, Exception: (9) closure(friend, a, b) ? when I query visible(a,b).

Comment: You need to use the definition for `closure/3` in the link above!

Answer (score 1):

```
visible(X,Y):- friends(X,YS), member(Y,YS).
visible(X,Y):- friends(X,XF), friends(Y,YF), member(Z,XF), member(Z,YF).
```

The first line checks if two people are directly friends (`Y` is in the list of friends of `X`). The second line checks if two peolpe are friend of friends (an element `Z` is both in the list of friends of `X` and `Y`. If you also want to know wich is the friend in common you could add `write(Z)`). In this case, for instance, `joe` is friend of `john` but no viceversa. If you want also this property you should add

```
visible(X,Y):- friends(Y,XS), member(X,XS).
```

Queries:

```
?-visible(john,serena).
true.

?-visible(joe,john).
true.

?-visible(john,joe).
true. (only if you add the third line of code).
```

Comment: When I try to query and get a true result, I must enter a '.' after 'true' to end the command. Do you know how does this happen?

Comment: @Shiloh_C what do you mean? What prolog do you use?