# Prolog - Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated. Recursion depth

Tags: recursion, prolog, instantiation-error

I'm new to prolog and want to limit recursion depth, but it keeps throwing "Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated" error. I'll generalise the problem to a graph.

```
edge(a,b).
edge(a,x).
edge(b,c).
edge(b,x).
edge(c,d).
```

So, there's a path from a to d: a-b-c-d
It's pretty easy to check if there's a path between two vertices:

```
path(X,Y) :- edge(X,Y).
path(X,Y) :- edge(X,Z), path(Z,Y).
```

Now I want to limit the length of the path to N:

```
limitedPath(X,Y,N) :- edge(X,Y), N >= 0.
limitedPath(X,Y,N) :- edge(X,Z),limitedPath(Z,Y,M), N = M + 1, N>0.
```

**limitedPath(a,b,2)** is true,
but **limitedPath(a,c,1)** throws "Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated", and I can't get the reason.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26946133/772868) for a general approach. That is: `closure(edge, A, B)`

Comment: `M` is not instantiated in the recursive call. If `N` is supposed to be a limit it makes more sense to subtract one, and before the call.

Comment: ah, a tutorial got me confused.

Comment: `N = M + 1` doesn't do what you think (unless you're using some funky version of Prolog like Visual, PDC, or Turbo Prolog). It attempts to unify the term in `N` with the term `+(M, 1)`. It does not evaluate `M + 1` and compare with `N`. You probably want `N is M + 1`. Or, as @false has in his answer, use CLP(FD), which is the preferred means of reasoning with integers in Prolog.

Comment: Yes, I got that. Thanks.

Comment: @mat: Note the tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To continue your idea:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

limitedPath(X,Y,N) :- N #>= 0, edge(X,Y).
limitedPath(X,Y,N) :- N #>= 0, N #= M+1, edge(X,Z), limitedPath(Z,Y,M).
```