# Prolog doesn't terminate after goal reordering

Tags: prolog, backtracking, failure-slice, non-termination

I'm currently working through the Learn Prolog Now examples and for the one [exercise](http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pagetype=html&pageid=lpn-htmlse12) I have a KB that runs out of local stack if I just have a tiny change in one rule. this is the KB:

```
byCar(auckland,hamilton). 
byCar(hamilton,raglan). 
byCar(valmont,saarbruecken). 
byCar(valmont,metz). 

byTrain(metz,frankfurt). 
byTrain(saarbruecken,frankfurt). 
byTrain(metz,paris). 
byTrain(saarbruecken,paris). 

byPlane(frankfurt,bangkok). 
byPlane(frankfurt,singapore). 
byPlane(paris,losAngeles). 
byPlane(bangkok,auckland). 
byPlane(singapore,auckland). 
byPlane(losAngeles,auckland).

travel(X,Y) :- byCar(X,Y).
travel(X,Y) :- byTrain(X,Y).
travel(X,Y) :- byPlane(X,Y).
```

and the relevant rule:

```
travel(X,Y) :- travel(X,Z), travel(Z,Y).
```

and this is the query in question which runs out of stack:

```
?- travel(valmont,losAngeles).
```

But if I change the rule to

```
travel(X,Y) :- travel(Z,Y), travel(X,Z).
```

Then it works.

If I trace the query I get quickly stuck like this:

```
   Redo: (17) travel(raglan, _6896) ? creep
   Call: (18) byPlane(raglan, _6896) ? creep
   Fail: (18) byPlane(raglan, _6896) ? creep
   Redo: (17) travel(raglan, _6896) ? creep
   Call: (18) travel(raglan, _6896) ? creep
   Call: (19) byCar(raglan, _6896) ? creep
   Fail: (19) byCar(raglan, _6896) ? creep
   Redo: (18) travel(raglan, _6896) ? creep
   Call: (19) byTrain(raglan, _6896) ? creep
   Fail: (19) byTrain(raglan, _6896) ? creep
   Redo: (18) travel(raglan, _6896) ? creep
   Call: (19) byPlane(raglan, _6896) ? creep
   Fail: (19) byPlane(raglan, _6896) ? creep
   Redo: (18) travel(raglan, _6896) ? creep
...
```

But I don't see why. Shouldn't it just understand that raglan is an endstation and thus it has to backtrack one level more?

Thanks!

*Edit: I use SWI Prolog*

*Edit: I found the problem after going through it step by step.
In the case of raglan, there is no rule to anywhere at all. Therefore, after trying `byPlane, byTrain, byCar`, it tries `travel(raglan, X)` again (the first goal of the last rule), thus looping.
But I don't see how the other rule is any better.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, goal ordering is really important in this case. As you figured out, your first formulation allows for finding another hypothetical connection from raglan to anywhere by going via a hypothetical another city Z, whose nonexistence is never proven because you keep looking for it be recursing infinitely. Really, the trace is your best friend here, but this is not trivial to get right. You also have to think about all the cases where one, both or none of the arguments are bound.

Your second formulation is not better at all, it just happens to fail on different cases:

```
travel(losAngeles, valmont).
ERROR: Out of local stack
```

I would propose to make your logic safer by distinguishing between a direct connection and a multi-stop journey:

```
connection(X,Y) :- byCar(X,Y).
connection(X,Y) :- byTrain(X,Y).
connection(X,Y) :- byPlane(X,Y).

travel(X,Y) :- connection(X,Y).
travel(X,Y) :- connection(X,Z), travel(Z,Y).
```

Goal order doesn't matter now because `travel` always requires some physical connection to exist (rather than a recursion) in order to proceed.

This also makes it easier to record the journey, which you would want anyway (right?):

```
connection(X,Y, car(X,Y))   :- byCar(X,Y).
connection(X,Y, train(X,Y)) :- byTrain(X,Y).
connection(X,Y, plane(X,Y)) :- byPlane(X,Y).

travel(X,Y,[Part])       :- connection(X,Y,Part).
travel(X,Y,[Part|Parts]) :- connection(X,Z,Part), travel(Z,Y,Parts).

?- travel(valmont, losAngeles, Journey).
Journey = [car(valmont, saarbruecken), train(saarbruecken, paris), plane(paris, losAngeles)]
```

And for the case where there is no valid trip:

```
travel(losAngeles, valmont, Journey).
false.
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense! This also nicely plays into the next chapter about lists :) Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You need to clarify what you mean by "it works".  In fact, both versions of the predicate `travel/2` do not terminate. But one happens to find a solution for a highly specific query.

Now ask `?- travel(hamilton, losAngeles).` which loops for both.

So your fix only works for some queries but not for others. Isn't there a more reliable way out?

In general, the very precise sequence of answer substitutions produced by Prolog is difficult to predict. You will have to simulate every tiny step Prolog takes.

On the other hand, there is a very related notion called (universal) **termination** which is much easier to predict as it is independent of many details in your program like the order in which your facts appear. The easiest way to query for universal termination is to add the goal **`false`** at the end of your query.

But you can go even further adding goals **`false`** wherever you want<sup>1</sup>. Such a modified program is called a [failure-slice](/questions/tagged/failure-slice). No matter how you insert **`false`** the following holds:

> If the failure-slice does not terminate, then also your original program does not terminate.

Now consider failure-slices for the two variants of `travel/2`:

```
travel(X,Y) :- false, byCar(X,Y).
travel(X,Y) :- false, byTrain(X,Y).
travel(X,Y) :- false, byPlane(X,Y).
travel(X,Y) :- travel(X,Z), false, travel(Z,Y).
```

And your other version:

```
travel(X,Y) :- false, byCar(X,Y).
travel(X,Y) :- false, byTrain(X,Y).
travel(X,Y) :- false, byPlane(X,Y).
travel(X,Y) :- travel(Z,Y), false, travel(X,Z).
```

In both, neither `X` nor `Y` is considered at all! So the two arguments do not influence termination. And thus both versions do not terminate. That is, they **never** terminate.

Now compare this conclusion to the more traditional approach of looking at a trace. While failure slices permitted us to make *general conclusions* ("... never terminates") a particular trace can only show you details of one particular execution.

In order to fix this you need to change something in the visible part.  My suggestion would be to use [`closure/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26946133/772868). That is:

```
travel(X, Y) :-
   closure(connexion, X, Y).

connexion(X,Y) :- byCar(X,Y).
connexion(X,Y) :- byTrain(X,Y).
connexion(X,Y) :- byPlane(X,Y).
```

Or use the more general [`path/4`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30328433/772868).

---

<sub>1 Actually, this only works in pure monotonic programs. Your program is one of those</sub>