# Having trouble thinking in prolog. Infinite recursion problem

Tags: prolog, transitive-closure

In reading a book on prolog I have come across trouble with this problem.

```
% Write a predicate travel_to/2 which determines whether it is possible to 
% travel from one place to another by chaining together car, train, and
% plane journeys. For example, your program should answer yes to the
% query travel_to(valmont,raglan).

by_car(auckland,hamilton).
by_car(hamilton,raglan).
by_car(valmont,saarbruecken).
by_car(valmont,metz).

by_train(metz,frankfurt).
by_train(saarbruecken,frankfurt).
by_train(metz,paris).
by_train(saarbruecken,paris).

by_plane(frankfurt,bangkok).
by_plane(frankfurt,singapore).
by_plane(paris,losAngeles).
by_plane(bangkok,auckland).
by_plane(singapore,auckland).
by_plane(losAngeles,auckland).

travel_to(X,Y) :- ( by_car(X,Y)
                  ; by_train(X,Y)
                  ; by_plane(X,Y)
                  ).
travel_to(X,Y) :-
    travel_to(X,Z),
    travel_to(Z,Y).
```

I am having a hard time seeing where the infinite recursion is coming from. I think about this code as so: "If X can travel to Y directly then we satisfy the predicate. Otherwise lets see if we can find recursive connections. Is there a Z that X connects to that then connects to Y?

swipl:

```
?- travel_to(valmont,raglan).
true ; % So it works?
ERROR: Stack limit (1.0Gb) exceeded
ERROR:   Stack sizes: local: 0.9Gb, global: 84.2Mb, trail: 0Kb
ERROR:   Stack depth: 11,028,501, last-call: 0%, Choice points: 12
ERROR:   Probable infinite recursion (cycle):
ERROR:     [11,028,501] user:travel_to(raglan, _22060066)
ERROR:     [11,028,500] user:travel_to(raglan, _22060086)
```

This should be false:

```
?- travel_to(losAngeles,metz).
ERROR: Stack limit (1.0Gb) exceeded
ERROR:   Stack sizes: local: 0.9Gb, global: 84.1Mb, trail: 0Kb
ERROR:   Stack depth: 11,028,558, last-call: 0%, Choice points: 6
ERROR:   Probable infinite recursion (cycle):
ERROR:     [11,028,558] user:travel_to(raglan, _22059564)
ERROR:     [11,028,557] user:travel_to(raglan, _22059584)
```

Comment: `travel_to(X,Y) :- travel_to(X,Z), travel_to(Z,Y).` will if the first `travel_to` clause fails, try the second one, but that is exactly the same, so the call stack will keep growing.

Comment: Out of interest, what book is this from? We had the exact same example last month: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63371755/why-does-my-prolog-rule-get-stuck-in-infinite-recursion/63374630

Comment: [learn prolog now](http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pageid=online)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your second clause:

```
travel_to(X, Y) :-
    travel_to(X, Z),
    travel_to(Z, Y).
```

will always match. Even if there is no destination originating from the `X` at all, `travel_to/2` will simply fallback on the recursive clause.

Even if we manage to fix that, it is still possible to get into infinite recursion, if for example there is `by_car(a, b)`, and a `by_train(b, a)`, then it is possible that prolog will search a path `a - b - a - b - …`.

There are basically two problems:

1. there is no *guaranteed progress*, so if no travel path leaves from `X` it will still keep calling `travel_to`; and
2. there is no guarantee we do not run into a cycle.

We can fix the first one by introducing a predicate `step/2` for example:

```
step(X,Y) :-
    by_car(X,Y).
step(X,Y) :-
    by_train(X,Y).
step(X,Y) :-
    by_plane(X,Y).
```

and next we can make a `travel_to/2` predicate which is the transitive closure of `step`:

```
travel_to(X, X).
travel_to(X, Z) :-
    step(X, Y),
    travel_to(Y, Z).
```

This predicate fixes the problem with the guaranteed progress, since the call to `step/2` forces Prolog to pick a path and thus make a hop. But it still can run into a cycle.

We can solve the second problem by maintaining a list of already visited nodes, and reject visiting the same node a second time:

```
travel_to(X, Y) :-
    travel_to(X, Y, [X]).

travel_to(X, X, _).
travel_to(X, Z, L) :-
    step(X, Y),
    \+ member(Y, L),
    travel_to(Y, Z, [Y|L]).
```

Comment: This is a very nice answer. You introduced ideas that I had not thought of. Lots to learn.

Comment: Nitpick: I wouldn't say that the clause will "always succeed". It will always *match* and be entered and recurse. But to me "success" is something you get on termination, and this clause will never terminate.