# Prolog program query not terminating

Tags: prolog, failure-slice

I aa new to prolog. I tried this simple program.

```
man(rahul).
person(X) :- man(X).
male(X) :- man(X).
female(X) :- \+ man(x).
female(samita).
married(samita, rahul).
loves(X, Y) :- married(X, Y).
married(X, Y) :- married(Y, X).
child(sita, samita, rahul).
loves(X, Y):- child(X, Y , Z).
loves(X, Z):- child(X, Y , Z).
```

my query is.

```
loves(sita, X).
```

According to me. the answer must be.

```
X = rahul.
X = samita.
```

but in swi prolog the program is not terminating.
can someone please help me with understanding where I did wrong.

code

```
man(rahul).
person(X) :- man(X).
male(X) :- man(X).
female(X) :- \+ man(x).
female(samita).
married(samita, rahul).
loves(X, Y) :- married(X, Y).
married(X, Y) :- married(Y, X).
child(sita, samita, rahul).
loves(X, Y):- child(X, Y , Z).
loves(X, Z):- child(X, Y , Z).
```

query:

```
loves(sita, X).
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do i get a stack limit exceeded error when defining a predicate that convert the relation of two atoms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55208901/why-do-i-get-a-stack-limit-exceeded-error-when-defining-a-predicate-that-convert)

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but you appear to have a typo `\+ man(x)` where the lowercase x (atom) should be an uppercase X (variable).

Answer (score 2):

To understand why your program loops, it is sufficient to look at the following [failure-slice](/questions/tagged/failure-slice). *Because* this fragment does not terminate, also your full program does not terminate.

```
loves(X, Y) :- married(X, Y), false.
loves(X, Y):- false, child(X, Y , Z).
loves(X, Z):- false, child(X, Y , Z).

married(samita, rahul) :- false.
married(X, Y) :- married(Y, X), false.

?- loves(sita, any), false.
   loops.
```

To fix this problem replace the clauses for `married/2` by

```
married(X, Y) :- husband_wife(X,Y).
married(X, Y) :- husband_wife(Y,X).

husband_wife(rahul,samita).

?- loves(sita, X).
   X = samita
;  X = rahul.
```