# Prolog Infinite loop on circular facts

Tags: prolog, transitive-closure, failure-slice

Here is circular part of my facts (define relation between people):

```
connection(harry, ron).
connection(ron, harry).
connection(hermione, harry).
```

I want to find out if there is a connection, either directly or through other people using recursion.

This code runs into an infinite loop in the above situation:

```
connected(A, B) :-
   connection(A, B).
connected(A, B) :- 
   connection(A, C),
   connected(C, B).
```

I want the recursion to stop when it encounters previous searches.
For example:

```
?- connected(hermione, X).
X = harry ;
X = ron.
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prolog's execution mechanism is quite un-intuitive. It combines recursion (as you know it from other languages) with backtracking.  But there is a nice way out.  You can consider smaller programs instead of your original program.

To better understand the actual loop, here is the minimal program fragment called a [failure-slice](/questions/tagged/failure-slice) that is the cause for non-termination.  There is some extra falsework in it: Some goals **`false`**. With these goals the number of inferences is reduced (or stays the same). Thus, when the resulting program is looping, this is also a reason why your original program loops.

```
connection(harry, ron).
connection(ron, harry).
connection(herminone, harry) :- false.

connected(A, B) :- false, connection(A, B).
connected(A, B) :-
    connection(A, C),
    connected(C, B), false.

?- connected(A, B).
```

The query still loops. Note that it fails (and thus terminates) when asked the right persons (you know who, I suppose):

```
?- connected(tom, B).
   false.
```

To solve this problem, the simplest way is to use [`closure/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26946133/772868) like so:

```
connected(A, B) :-
   closure(connection, A, B).
```

Comment: You really like your nickname, don't you? ;-)

Comment: [Falsework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falsework) I only learned very [recently](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=falsework).

Comment: It's helpful though.

Answer (score 1):

You could try tabling. Many Prolog systems have table/1 directive. You just have to place it before the predicate you want to tabulate.

```
:- table connected/2.
connected(A, B) :-
   connection(A, B).
connected(A, B) :- 
   connection(A, C),
   connected(C, B).
```

If you then run a query, recursion will automatically stop. Here is an example run with the SWI-Prolog tabling:

```
Welcome to SWI-Prolog (threaded, 64 bits, version 8.1.4)

?- connected(hermione, X).
X = harry ;
X = ron.
```

Comment: For SWI-Prolog: `:- use_module(library(tabling)).
:- table connected/2, connection/2.`

Comment: [connection/2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55340773/502187) is already a table, so you don't need to table it.