# Prolog order of clauses causes pathfinding to fail

Tags: prolog, transitive-closure

I am developing a path finding algorithm in Prolog, giving all nodes accessible by a path from a starting node. To avoid duplicate paths, visited nodes are kept in a list.

Nodes and neighbors are defined as below:

```
node(a).
node(b).
node(c).
node(d).
node(e).

edge(a,b).
edge(b,c).
edge(c,d).
edge(b,d).

neighbor(X,Y) :- edge(X,Y).
neighbor(X,Y) :- edge(Y,X).
```

The original algorithm below works fine:

```
path2(X,Y) :-
    pathHelper(X,Y,[X]).

pathHelper(X,Y,L) :-
    neighbor(X,Y),
    \+ member(Y,L).
pathHelper(X,Y,H) :-
    neighbor(X,Z),
    \+ member(Z,H),
    pathHelper(Z,Y,[Z|H]).
```

This works fine

```
[debug]  ?- path2(a,X).
X = b ;
X = c ;
X = d ;
X = d ;
X = c ;
false.
```

however, when changing the order of the two clauses in the second definition, such as below

```
pathHelper(X,Y,L) :-
    \+ member(Y,L),
    neighbor(X,Y).
```

When trying the same here, swipl returns the following:

```
[debug]  ?- path2(a,X).
false.
```

The query doesn't work anymore, and only returns `false`. I have tried to understand this through the `trace`command, but still can't make sense of what exactly is wrong.

In other words, I am failing to understand why the order of `neighbor(X,Y)`and `\+ member(Y,L)`is crucial here. It makes sense to have `neighbor(X,Y)` first in terms of efficiency, but not in terms of correctness to me.

Comment: Can you provide some input data and a query?

Answer (score 1):

You are now encountering the not so clean-cut borders of pure Prolog and its illogical surroundings. [Welcome to the real world](https://youtu.be/QXBPJ5FLqCU?t=168).

Or rather, not welcome! Instead, let's try to improve your definition.  The key problem is

```
\+ member(Y, [a]), Y = b.
```

which fails while

```
Y = b, \+ member(Y,[a]).
```

succeeds. There is no logic to justify this. It's just the operational mechanism of Prolog's built-in `(\+)/1`.

Happily, we can improve upon this. Enter [`non_member/2`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26946133/772868).

```
non_member(_X, []).
non_member(X, [E|Es]) :-
   dif(X, E),
   non_member(X, Es).
```

Now,

```
?- non_member(Y, [a]).
dif(Y,a).
```

Mark this answer, it says: Yes, `Y` is not an element of `[a]`, provided `Y` is different from `a`.  Think of the many solutions this answer includes, like `Y = 42`, or `Y = b` and infinitely many more such solutions that are not `a`.  Infinitely many solutions captured in nine characters!

Now, both `non_member(Y, [a]), Y = b` and `Y = b, non_member(Y, [a])` succeed.  So exchanging them has only influence on runtime and space consumption.  If we are at it, note that you check for non-memberness in two clauses. You can factor this out. For a generic solution to this, see [closure/3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26946133/772868). With it, you simply say: `closure(neighbor, A,B).`

Also consider the case where you have only `edge(a,a)`. Your definition fails here for `path2(a,X)`. But shouldn't this rather succeed?

And the name `path2/2` is not that fitting, rather reserve this word for an [actual path](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30328433/772868).

Answer (score 0):

The doubt you have is related to how prolog handle negation. Prolog uses negation as failure. This means that, if prolog has to negate a goal `g` (indicate it with `not(g)`), it tries to prove `g` by executing it and then, if the `g` fails, `not(g)` (or `\+ g`, i.e. the negation of `g`) succeeds and viceversa.

Keep in mind also that, after the execution of `not(g)`, if the goal has variables, they will not be instantiated. This because prolog should instantiate the variables with all the terms that makes `g` fail, and this is likely an infinite set (for example for a list, `not(member(A,[a])` should instantiate the variable `A` with all the elements that are not in the list).

Let's see an example. Consider this simple program:

```
test:-
    L = [a,b,c],
    \+member(A,L),
    writeln(A).
```

and run it with `?- trace, test.` First of all you get a `Singleton variable in \+: A` warning for the reason i explained before, but let's ignore it and see what happens.

```
Call:test
 Call:_5204=[a, b]
 Exit:[a, b]=[a, b]
 Call:lists:member(_5204, [a, b])
 Exit:lists:member(a, [a, b]) % <-----
 Fail:test
false
```

You see at the highlighted line that the variable `A` is instantiated to `a` and so `member/2` succeeds and so `\+ member(A,L)` is false.

So, in your code, if you write `pathHelper(X,Y,L) :- \+ member(Y,L), neighbor(X,Y).`, this clause will always fail because `Y` is not sufficiently instantiated. If you swap the two terms, `Y` will be ground and so `member/2` can fail (and `\+member` succeeds).

Comment: *because `Y` is not ground*: That is not the reason. It's rather because `Y` is not sufficiently instantiated. If `Y` would be, say `_-_`, that would be no problem.

Comment: Yes, my bad. Fixed