# Prolog - why does the following code generate the solution X=root forever?

Tags: prolog, failure-slice

```
black(root). 
black(v1). 
black(v3). 
black(v4). 

edge(root,root).
edge(v1,root). 
edge(v2,v1). 
edge(v3,v1). 
edge(v4,v3). 
edge(v5,v2). 
edge(v5,v4). 
edge(v6,v5). 

foo(root). 
foo(X) :- edge(X,Y), black(Y), foo(Y).
```

Then I type `foo(X)` and only get `X=root`.

I really can't figure out why. We get the first `root` because of the first part of foo. Then we are supposed to go the the second part, we then proceed to find the edge `(root,root)`. `black(root)` returns true and so does `foo(root)` so we get another root `solution`. Why don't we then go to the edge `(v1,root)`? What am I missing?

Comment: You made an infinte loop, since for `foo(root)`, it can each time also take the recurive case, unify with `edge(root, root)`, and thus find another solution. Prolog searches *depth-first*, not *breadth-first*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because looking for the 3rd solution starts with retrying `foo(Y)` when `Y=root`, and you've already established there are at least 2 distinct ways to prove `foo(root)`.  (But, as @WillemVanOnsem points out, it is much worse than that.)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fragment that is responsible for non-termination called a [failure-slice](/questions/tagged/failure-slice). You need to modify the remaining part somehow in order to avoid that loop.

```
black(root).
black(v1) :- false. 
black(v3) :- false. 
black(v4) :- false. 

edge(root,root).
edge(v1,root) :- false. 
edge(v2,v1) :- false. 
edge(v3,v1) :- false. 
edge(v4,v3) :- false. 
edge(v5,v2) :- false. 
edge(v5,v4) :- false. 
edge(v6,v5) :- false. 

foo(root) :- false. 
foo(X) :- edge(X,Y), black(Y), foo(Y), false.
```

The easiest way to solve this is to reuse [`closure0/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26946133/772868).

```
edgeb(X, Y) :-
   edge(X, Y),
   black(Y).

foo(X) :-
   closure0(edgeb, X, root).
```

... or change your facts.  The [failure-slice](/questions/tagged/failure-slice) above showed us that the `edge(root,root).` was part of the problem. What, if we just remove that very fact? Or turn it into

```
edge(root,root) :- false.
```

Now `foo(X)` terminates:

```
?- foo(X).
   X = root
;  X = v1
;  X = v2
;  X = v3
;  X = v4
;  X = v5
;  false.
```

To avoid hammering <kbd>;</kbd> or <kbd>SPACE</kbd> so many times, your carpal tunnels recommend:

```
?- foo(X), false.
false.
```

By that we have **proven** that your program will terminate **always**. There cannot be any special case lurking around.