# Setting up a rule?

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to rule to check if someone likes a friend other than the one stated in the argument. So for example,

```
likes(Alice,Bob).
likes(Bob,Alice).
likes(Alice,Jeff).
likes(Jeff,Alice).
```

I'm trying to create a rule `friends(X,Y)` that if both of them like each other, we look for another pair that either `X` or `Y` is linked to. Any help?

Comment: Are you saying that you only want your predicate is `friends\2` to succeed if there exists a third person that either of the given people also like?

Comment: What have you tried? Can you at least write out most of the program so that we have as little to do as possible? We're not a code writing service you know.

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60883594/recursive-loop-exit-statement-needed

Comment: constants are written starting with a lowercase. By using `Alice` and `Bob`, you basically say that everyone is friends with everyone.

Comment: Please specify how the predicate should look like, what the knowledge base is, what the expected output is, and your own attempt to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

The first solution returns the first person found that one of the two people likes, in case these 2 people like each other.

```
likes(alice,bob).
likes(bob,alice).
likes(alice,jeff).
likes(jeff,alice). 

friends_aux(X, Y, Z) :- likes(Y, Z), Z \= X.
friends_aux(X, Y, Z) :- likes(X, Z), Z \= Y.
friends(X, Y, Z) :- likes(X, Y), likes(Y, X), friends_aux(X, Y, Z), !.
```

And the second solution returns true if any of the two people have any other couple.

```
friends2_aux(X, Y) :- likes(Y, Z), Z \= X.
friends2_aux(X, Y) :- likes(X, Z), Z \= Y.
friends2(X, Y) :- likes(X, Y), likes(Y, X), friends2_aux(X, Y), !.
```

**I attached an image of the results.**

**[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsvZ0.png)**

Hopefully this is what you wanted.