# Write a predicate that works for cyclic graph to check if there exists a path between two nodes using prolog

Tags: prolog, predicate, cyclic-graph

I am trying to wrote a predicate isway(A, B) which should work for cyclic graphs. The expected outcome I am trying to get is, if there a path exists between 2 nodes or not. example: if I ask isway(a, f),  expect it to answer either yes or no. below is my code but it never works and always gives me false as an output.

```
%given facts

edge(a,b).
edge(a,c).
edge(b,c).
edge(c,d).
edge(c,e).
edge(d,e).
edge(f,g).
edge(g,h).

edge2(d,a).
edge2(h,f).
edge2(X,Y) :- edge(X,Y).

%my implementation
isway(A,B) :- edge2(A,B,[]).

edge2(A,B,V) :- edge(A,X), not(member(X,V)), (B = X ; edge2(X,B,[A|V])).

%my output
?- isway(b,a). %I expect true for this one
false

?- isway(a,f). %False for this is ok but I am not confident about my logic
false.
```

Comment: If edge/2 are undirected, then you need a predicate like `edge(From,To) :- edge(To,From).` but then this opens a new can of worms that you will have to resolve.

Comment: yep. I added but it seem to give me similar result. not much changed.

Comment: `isway(A, B) :- closure(edge, A, B).` See [`closure/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26946133/772868).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [tabling](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=tabling) for computing the transitive closure of the edge relation:

```
edge(a,b).
edge(a,c).
edge(b,c).
edge(c,d).
edge(c,e).
edge(d,e).
edge(f,g).
edge(g,h).

edge(d,a). % acyclic
edge(h,f). % acyclic

:- table path/2.
path(X, Y) :- edge(X, Y).
path(X, Y) :- path(X, Z), path(Z, Y).
```

Then, the queries work as you expect:

```
?- path(a, f).
false.

?- path(b, a).
true.
```